# Why is Tromsø Airport's runway 01 referred to as 36 in the sign before the runway?

Tags: runways

Runway designations can change due to the changing direction of the magnetic north. Using Google Earth, we can verify that Tromsø Airport's runway 01 has not changed its designation since at least 2005. Nevertheless, as we can see at the start of [this video](https://youtu.be/byExWVYkqSY) the sign just before the runway refers to the runway as runway 36. Does the 36 on the sign refer to the true direction while the number painted on the runway is the compass direction?

Comment: Also, closely related: [How do airports determine when they should change their runway numbers?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/648/how-do-airports-determine-when-they-should-change-their-runway-numbers)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The runway number is changed to **18/36** due to the change of magnetic variation. The image on Google Earth must be outdated. This is from my current (AIRAC 2004) Jeppesen airport chart of ENTC (Tromso, Norway):

[image: ENTC]

The video you linked was uploaded in March 2020, were the runway number had already been changed. I do not know how old the Google Earth image is. According to [this thread](https://forum.aerosoft.com/index.php?/topic/146947-tromso-x/) on a simulation forum, the runway number was changed with AIRAC 1910, which came into effect on **12 Sep 2019**.

By the way, both the numbers on the runway and the sign refer the magnetic heading. For more details, see [How are runways numbered?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-are-runways-numbered).

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding it, [Google Map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Troms%C3%B8+Airport/@69.6731296,18.910499,405m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x5040733cf2f3e30e!8m2!3d69.6819354!4d18.9162637) stated that the imagery data is from 2020, but the paint on the runway is still 01/19.

Comment: @AndrewT. No, that 2020 is the copyright information, not the year when the image was taken. See [this Google support question](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/3134029?hl=en): "You can only check the age of satellite imagery using Google Earth Pro".